# How to overwrite the dump/load methods in the pickle class - customizing pickling and unpickling - Python

Tags: python, pickle

So far, what I've done is this:

```
import pickle

class MyPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def __init__(self, file, protocol=None):
        super(MyPickler, self).__init__(file, protocol)

class MyUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super(MyUnpickler, self).__init__(file)
```

In my main method, this is mainly what I have

```
#created object, then... 
pickledObject = 'testing.pickle'
with open(pickledObject,'wb') as f:
    pickle = MyPickler(f)
    pickle.dump(object) #object is the object I want to pickle, created before this

with open(pickledObject, 'r') as pickledFile:
    unpickle = MyUnpickler(pickledFile)
    object2 = unpickle.load()
```

However, this is giving me the following error when the super method is called:
`TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

How does one overwrite only the two methods, load and dump? The pickle file is under C:\Python27/lib/pickle.py

**EDIT**
The enum.py file can be found here: http://dpaste.com/780897/

Object details:
Object is initialized like this:

```
object = CellSizeRelation(CellSizeRelation.Values.FIRST)
```

And CellSizeRelation is a class that uses the Enumeration:

```
class CellSizeRelation(Option):
    Values = enum.Enum('FIRST',
                       'SECOND')
```

Before I pickle object, I do this:

```
print object.Values._values 
print object.value.enumtype
```

*output*

```
[EnumValue(<enum.Enum object at 0x02E80E50>, 0, 'FIRST'), EnumValue(<enum.Enum object at 0x02E80E50>, 1, 'SECOND')
<enum.Enum object at 0x02E80E50>
```

After I unpickle and print out the same thing, I get this *output*:

```
[EnumValue(<enum.Enum object at 0x02E80E50>, 0, 'FIRST'), EnumValue(<enum.Enum object at 0x02E80E50>, 1, 'SECOND')
<enum.Enum object at 0x02ECF750>
```

The problem is that the second object address changes; When initialized the first time, the `enumtype` and `_values` have the same address. However, after unpickling, they change addresses. This breaks my code when I try to compare two enumValues. If you look in the `enumValue` class, the compare function tries to do this:

```
try:
        assert self.enumtype == other.enumtype
        result = cmp(self.index, other.index)
```

Because the address changes, the assert function fails. 
I now somehow need to ensure that the address for the enumtype does not change when unpickled. I was thinking of simply getting the value 'FIRST' from the unpickled file, finding out its index, and reinitializing the object with:

```
def load:
    object = CellSizeRelation(CellSizeRelation.Values[INDEX])
    return object
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: First, is there a reason you need to use inheritance/subclassing instead of composition/aggregation here? If there is, you have to deal with the fact that pickle.Pickler is not guaranteed to be a new-style class in Python 2.x, and from the error it seems as if it isn't one in your case, which makes things harder than you probably want to deal with if you don't already know the difference between type and classobj.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have an enumeration class (not written by me) and it contains values. The enumeration is pretty much a list, and the class has some methods. Well, when I initialize an enumeration object, with a type from the list, the address of the enumeration type and the object inside are the same. However, after I unpickle, these addresses change, thus breaking my code further down. So the goal is to make these two addresses the same when I unpickle... Honestly, I'm not even too sure what I'm really trying to do, but I hope my explanation cleared out some things?

Comment: @abarnert I am a beginner (first months on my first job), so this error is definitely perplexing me. There is no particular reason why I have to use inheritance, but I was hoping that would be the easiest way to fix the problem. How would I use composition/aggregation?

Comment: @Dana: You may want to communicate what these enumeration classes look like, and what goes wrong. Subclassing the pickler and unpickler is *almost certainly* not the way to go though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Okay, I'll change my question. I'll have it ready in about 5 minutes

Comment: The reason why I'm getting the TypeError is because the original Pickler and Unpickler classes don't inherit from object (I researched after I read abarnert's comment). If I try to change either class to inherit from object, the file doesn't allow me to save.

Comment: Note that `enum.py` you shared is basically the `enum` package as published on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yup, I realized after I read the top of my file that it was made by someone public - That's why I didn't mind posting the code up :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to customize the way object state is pickled and unpickled, not customize the load and unload functionality.

You'll have to study the [Pickling and unpickling normal class instances chapter](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances), in your case defining a `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` method should be enough.

What happens in your case is that there is a class-level attribute with `EnumValue` instances, which are meant to be constants. But on unpickling, new `EnumValue` instances are created that are not connected to the class-level attribute anymore.

The `EnumValue` instances do have an `index` attribute you can use to capture their state as an integer instead of an instance of `EnumValue`, which we can use to find the correct constant again when reinstating your instances:

```
 class CellSizeRelation(Option):
     # skipping your enum definition and __init__ here

     def __getstate__(self):
         # capture what is normally pickled
         state = self.__dict__.copy()
         # replace the `value` key (now an EnumValue instance), with it's index:
         state['value'] = state['value'].index
         # what we return here will be stored in the pickle
         return state

     def __setstate__(self, newstate):
         # re-create the EnumState instance based on the stored index
         newstate['value'] = self.Values[newstate['value']]
         # re-instate our __dict__ state from the pickled state
         self.__dict__.update(newstate)
```

So, normally, if there is no `__getstate__` the instance `__dict__` is pickled. We now do return a copy of that `__dict__`, but we swapped out the `EnumValue` instance for it's index (a simple integer). On unpickling, normally the new instance `__dict__` is updated with the unpickled `__dict__` we captured on pickling, but now that we have a `__setstate__` defined, we can swap out the enum index back out for the correct `EnumValue` again.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumValue` is depending on `id` identity between the `Enum` "enumeration type" objects. This has some advantages and disadvantages.

The main advantage is that two calls to `Enum('A', 'B')` define different enumeration types. So:

```
osx = Enum('Jaguar', 'Tiger', 'Leopard')
bigcats = Enum('Jaguar', 'Tiger', 'Leopard')
```

If you want to be able to distinguish OS X 10.4 from a striped killing machine, this can be useful.

But this also means that when pickle unpickles `osx` and `bigcats`, they're not only going to be distinct from each other, they're also going to be distinct from any earlier instances of `osx` and `bigcats`. There's really now any around that, once you think about it.

So, your solution can't involve any kind of hacking pickle; it's going to have to involve hacking the `enum` module.

You're going to need to define a reasonable `__cmp__` method for `Enum` that does what makes sense for you. If you can abandon the osx-vs.-bigcats distinction, that's easy. If you can't, you need some other way (maybe adding an explicit tag name to the `enum` definition, or an optional-but-otherwise-implicitly-autoincrementing counter?) that handles it.

Comment: Nope, you can hack the state capturing and reinstating.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you can't force it to generate the same id as an already-existing object, so what's the point?

Comment: You can *retrieve* the original object, which is still there. Note my answer; we avoid the whole issue by not pickling the enum values, we store their index instead, then restore the enum on unpickling.

Comment: Each newly unpickled `Enum` is a unique object, so not equal to any other. You need some way to determine which `Enum` you want your `EnumValue` to be an instance of. You can make that the responsibility of every object that owns an `EnumValue`, or you can change `Enum` as I described above, but you have to do it somewhere. (And you can only retrieve the original object if you're pickling and unpickling in the same process. Obviously once you quit and relaunch, the original object doesn't exist anymore.)

Comment: @abarnert Hey, abarnert! First of all, thanks for answering! I did make a compare function inside my CellSizeRelation, but my mentor told me that it'd be better if I overwrite the pickling method somehow, so I don't have to make a new compare methods for all my enumerations. I was also thinking of changing the compare function, but my mentor suggested against that -- I guess the downside of your first job/internship is that a lot of creativity gets taken away =/. Thanks again though!